# What is missing after Bridging Obj-C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I have done this before, normally without trouble, setting the bridging header, etc.
This time, I tried to import a Obj-C framwork (github.com/jensmeder/FSKModem/) into my swift project. When typing code I can "see" all the Obj-C methods.

But when I compile the code, I get errors like "Use of undeclared identifier 'delete'" or "Use of undeclared identifier 'new'". Example of code in a .m file that is giving the error:

```
    _audioFormat = new AudioStreamBasicDescription();
```

I'm familiar with Swift and don't know about Obj-C but I guess "delete" or "new" should exist, right? Do they belong to some framework that I should add?
I can compile the original code in Obj-C without trouble, but I need to incorporate it in my project that is written in Swift.

Many thanks for any help

Some more information...
The following functions are inside the .m file. Do you know why the "new" and "delete" keywords are unrecognized? This works fine when compiled as a normal "Obj-C" project. The error appears in Swift project only (after bridging headers of course):

```
-(void)dealloc
{
[self disconnect:NULL];

if (_audioFormat)
{
    delete _audioFormat;
}
}

-(void) setupAudioFormat
{
_audioFormat = new AudioStreamBasicDescription();
//...
}
```

Should I add some #include that I might be missing, besides Foundation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new` and `delete` are C++ keywords; you can use them in C++ files (usually `.cpp` or `.cc`) and in Objective-C++ files (always `.mm`). You cannot use them in Swift (`.swift`) or in Objective-C (`.m`) files.

It is perfectly valid to use an Objective-C class from an Objective-C++ file from Swift; you can use Objective-C to wrap C++ classes for Swift usage. However it is not valid to use C++ from plain Objective-C.

Quite probably you just need to rename your Objective-C file to `.mm`.

Comment: Hi, after following your suggestion I get the following error instead: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: (then a big list of them).

Comment: I managed to compile. Just started all over from a blank project and used your tip to rename to .mm  Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`new` and `delete` are keywords from C++ not from Swift or Objective-C.

### Swift

```
let audioFormat = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
```

### Objective-C

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription* audioFormat = [[AudioStreamBasicDescription alloc] init];
```

Comment: Thanks. That portion of code is inside a .m file. Shouldn't I be able to use that library without touching its contents?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, you simply need to call the object initializer when creating an object.

```
_audioFormat = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
```

The `new` keyword is an Objective-C combo of `alloc` and `init`.